# Scripted interaction with GUI elements in Python under Linux

Tags: python, automation

A while ago I used a python framework that could control the mouse and keyboard of the machine it was running on, and it made it possible to automate GUI interaction. Is there anything like this for Linux? I need to control an application running under Wine which doesn't seem to follow most windows convention, so I would guess that this excludes many solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a application called "Dogtail" by red hat that uses python framework. http://www.redhat.com/magazine/020jun06/features/dogtail/

Also, found a package for python called autopy
http://www.autopy.org/